# AngularJS: strange behavior on templateUrl in directive(template works well)

Tags: angularjs, templates, directive

I have two directives, one is table, the other one is button.
But when I use templateUrl in button directive, all buttons are displayed in the same line in table. 
But "template" can work well.
Anyone can help on this?

The plunker of these two demos are listed below: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/9EaRfrSQggPETrXhNZvq?p=preview : using templateUrl
http://plnkr.co/edit/UHzEpugxtM6JjoNrUd9X?p=preview : using template

The only difference between directives myButton1 and myButton2 is :
**myButton1** uses :
**templateUrl**: function (element, attrs) {
    return TEMPLATE_ACTION;
}
The content of "actionTemplate.html" is:

```
<div ng-if="config !== undefined">b</div><br/><br/>
```

**myButton2** uses :
**template**: '`<div ng-if="config !== undefined">b</div>`',

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.data = [
                    {name: 'field1', config: {type: 'config1'}},
                    {name: 'field2', config: {type: 'config2'}}
                ];
            }])
            .directive('myGrid', ['$compile', function($compile) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    replace: true,
                    template: '' +
                        '<table>' +
                        '<tbody>' +
                        '<tr ng-repeat="item in data">' +
                        '    <td><div><my-button2 config="item.config"></my-button2></div></td>' +
                        '    <td>{{item.name}}</td>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                        '</tbody>' +
                        '</table>',
                    scope: true
                }
                }])
            .directive("myButton1", ["$compile",
                function ($compilee) {
                    var TEMPLATE_ACTION = 'views/actionTemplate.html';
                    return {
                        restrict: "E",
                        replace: true,
                        scope: true,
                        templateUrl: function (element, attrs) {
                            return TEMPLATE_ACTION;
                        },
                        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                            var config = scope.$eval(iAttrs.config);
                            scope.config = config;
                        }
                    };
                }
            ])
    ;
```

The result is that two buttons are displayed in the same line as below:
[image: wrong result]

But one use "template" in the directive, it works well:

```
        angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.data = [
                    {name: 'field1', config: {type: 'config1'}},
                    {name: 'field2', config: {type: 'config2'}}
                ];
            }])
            .directive('myGrid', ['$compile', function($compile) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    replace: true,
                    template: '' +
                        '<table>' +
                        '<tbody>' +
                        '<tr ng-repeat="item in data">' +
                        '    <td><div><my-button2 config="item.config"></my-button2></div></td>' +
                        '    <td>{{item.name}}</td>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                        '</tbody>' +
                        '</table>',
                    scope: true
                }
                }])
            .directive("myButton2", ["$compile",
                function ($compilee) {
                    return {
                        restrict: "E",
                        replace: true,
                        scope: true,
                        template: '<div ng-if="config !== undefined">b</div>',
                        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                            var config = scope.$eval(iAttrs.config);
                            scope.config = config;
                        }
                    };
                }
            ])
    ;
```

The result is as below:
[image: right result]

Comment: Could u create a fiddle to show the problem? I created one myself as u described but there was nothing different in results. Maybe there is something wrong with `actionTemplate.html`

Comment: plunker has been created for your reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/9EaRfrSQggPETrXhNZvq?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a known issue when using `ng-repeat`, `templateUrl`, `ng-if` and `replace:true` at the same time though it is said to be fixed multiple times.

Could be problems with the `transclude` logic inside angular.

`ng-if` and `ng-repeat` are two special directives in angular and at the same time, the DOM in `templateUrl` is loaded asynchronously and suspend the compilation. This complex situation will somehow generate the issue.

To avoid this, just use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`, or `template` instead of `templateUrl`, or set a script template for the templateUrl to put it in `$templateCache`.

Known issue reference (or u can google more for yourself)

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14326 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11855 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7183

Comment: thanks guy, I tried on templateUrl, template, replace and found below approach can solve this issue: delete "replace: true" and add "trunsclude: true". Any idea on this ?